# karnaugh to supplying to decoder

Tags: decoder, karnaugh-map

$$ F(A,B,C,D)= Σ(1,7,8,9,13,15) $$
if possible, simplify then, make it by using decoders and logic gates.

I've simplified it by Kmap and found as $$ F = \overline{B}\overline{C}D + A\overline{B}\overline{C} + A\overline{C}D + BCD $$

[image]

but how can I supply using decoder. Unfortunately, I don't understand decoders. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcAee6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why didn't we also connect `13` ?